# How to write library in ES.Next

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony

I'm a lot have read about ES.Next and I'm have question about ES.Next Modules.
In this time all JavaScript programmer's write JavaScript libraries in Anonymous functions.
Something like jQuery:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    // ...
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})( window );
```

underscore:

```
(function() {
    // ...
}).call( this );
```

But how all change when JavaScript get's Modules?

```
// MyLibrary.js
module MyLibrary {
    export function Hello() {
        console.log( 'Hello' );
    }
}

// Example.js
import Hello from MyLibrary;

Hello(); // Hello
```

Or Modules too need write in Anonymous functions? How about Global variables? And how all JavaScript coding style change when come ES.Next?

Comment: For detailed information, see http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules

Answer (score 0):

In es6 a script is implicitly a module so explicitly declaring a module is not required. Each of the files in this folder are modules and should help demonstrate actual es6 usage patterns. https://github.com/Benvie/continuum/tree/gh-pages/engine/builtins

Comment: To be useful as a module, however, a ES6 source file would need to contain at least some export declarations, which are not allowed on the toplevel of a script.